# SQL return select values and set variables at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server stored procedure, I retrieve data and set variables at the same time. Can we do that at the same time or we have to write two different select statements?

```
SELECT 
    username, firstname, lastname, phone
FROM 
    userTable

SELECT 
    @username = username,
    @firstname = firstname,
    @lastname = lastname,
    @phone = phone
FROM 
    userTable
```

Comment: Yes we can do it at same time

Comment: @Anurag could you please tell me how.

Comment: Check below solution for the same and let me know if do not work for you.

Comment: Is that working for you If yes please mark it as answer so that it can help other also

Comment: ***NO*** - in SQL Server / T-SQL, you ***cannot*** set variable values and return a result set in a single query. As you already have it, you need **two separate** queries - one for each operation

Comment: I want to assign values to variables and also return that row from stored proc , so i was wondering instead of doing it separately can we combine these two operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, can't mix variable assignment and output in the same statement. But you can avoid going through the table twice if you first assign to variables and then select their values:

```
SELECT @username=username,
       @firstname=firstname,
       @lastname=lastname,
       @phone=phone
FROM 
       userTable


SELECT @username username,
       @firstname firstname,
       @lastname lastname,
       @phone phone
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the variable in the select statement to store the values retrieved from Select statement.

```
DECLARE @username varchar(max);
DECLARE @firstname varchar(max);
DECLARE @lastname varchar(max);
DECLARE @phone varchar(max);

SELECT @username=username,
   @firstname=firstname,
   @lastname=lastname,
   @phone=phone
FROM 
   userTable
```

Comment: I think this is same as my solution nothing new .

Comment: This ***only*** sets the variable values - but it ***does not*** return a result set from the stored procedure

Comment: @anurag looks like you have deleted your ans

Comment: @Nikki Yes because some vote down to it  Don't know why